# Why <marker> doesn't orientate as the <path>

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a curved arrow with svg. I'm using [d3.line()](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#lines) to generate the path.

```js
let points = [
    [400,100],
    [450,200],
    [350,200],
    [385,275]
] 
let path = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal)(points)

console.log(path)
// -> M400,100C400,100,458.3333333333333,183.33333333333334,450,200C441.6666666666667,216.66666666666666,360.8333333333333,187.5,350,200C339.1666666666667,212.5,385,275,385,275
```

But when I try to use this result in a svg:

```html
<svg width="1200" height="1200" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <defs>
            <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <path d="M400,100C400,100,458.3333333333333,183.33333333333334,450,200C441.6666666666667,216.66666666666666,360.8333333333333,187.5,350,200C339.1666666666667,212.5,385,275,385,275"
            stroke-width="2" stroke="lightblue" fill="none" style="marker-end: url(#Triangle);"></path>
    </svg>
```

And here is the SVG result

[image].

I can't figure out why the marker doesn't orientate. Is there a better library to generate path to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour. The issue is that in a [cardinal spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Cardinal_spline)...

> Two additional points are required on either end of the curve.

And those points seem to interfere with the marker orientation (which is indeed the case, see [LeBeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50020869/5768908)).

You can easily see this if you change the curve. For instance, using `curveBasis`:

```js
let points = [
    [400,100],
    [450,200],
    [350,200],
    [385,275]
] 
let path = d3.line().curve(d3.curveBasis)(points)

d3.select("#myPath").attr("d", path);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1200" height="1200" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
            <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <path id="myPath" stroke-width="2" stroke="lightblue" fill="none" style="marker-end: url(#Triangle);"></path>
</svg>
```

In your case, a solution (arguably a hack) may be adding a final line to the path, just 1px away from the final point:

```
path = path + "L387,277";
```

Here is the demo:

```js
let points = [
    [400,100],
    [450,200],
    [350,200],
    [385,275]
] 
let path = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal)(points)

path = path + "L387,277";

d3.select("#myPath").attr("d", path);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1200" height="1200" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
            <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <path id="myPath" stroke-width="2" stroke="lightblue" fill="none" style="marker-end: url(#Triangle);"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: @ivanross. If you can, try using a curve type other than `curveCardinal`. For instance, `curveBasis` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @gerardo furtado, would you do an edit if possible (to remove the dv)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yes, it works with `curveBasis`, but unfortunately I have to use cardinal =(

Answer (score 2):

This is because the last control point and the end-point of your path have the same coordinates: (385,275).

SVG uses the control point vector to work out what the curve direction is at that point.  If your control point vector is from (385,275) to (385,275), then it can't determine the angle. So it defaults to an angle of 0 degrees.

Comment: I wonder who downvoted my answer though. What does the second point say?

Comment: @ibowankenobi well, we may never know the downvoter... but, unfortunately, your answer is not exactly correct, when you say *"based on the ending of the path, the interpolation of the orientation might look incorrect"*. The path d attribute is correct, that's the expected path for a cardinal spline. It adds additional points, which makes the orientation wrong.

Comment: My answer is correct. It is because of his last control point, I said this in my second bullet point. But someone didn't like the way I said it so he/she downvoted it. I don't like this sort of behavior so I downvoted him. Now the only difference between me and him is that I have the honesty, whereas he does not.

Comment: Gerardo I got your back!   @ibowankenobi I confess that was me. I downvoted because it just discusses the question rather than explaining the cause or offering a workable solution.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks. Your answer is nice because, although laconic, even explain the default behaviour (zero angle), which I missed in mine.

Comment: OP thought the marker orientation was not updated. I told what is going on my second point and demonstrated with straight lines that updating takes place. That's all I did. Now since you come out, paul can edit his answer so I can remove the downvote since it is locked now.

Comment: To get this back on track, it might be worth noting, that this is just an error in *The Browser* —aka Chrome— while other browser surrogates—namely FF and IE—will display this just fine. Related: [*"Marker won't follow orientation of a cardinal-curved path in d3"*](/q/40593094). Chromium bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=450368. @GerardoFurtado

Comment: @altocumulus So, now the question is: how do FF and IE calculate the correct angle if the last control point and the target point coincide?

Comment: @Gerardo Well, the path is rendered, so there obviously *is* an angle. The control points are just that: *control* points that determine the shape of the curve. In most cases these points won't even be part of the visual path: http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-curves/cubic-curve.html. Given that, it is fairly easy to understand, that there will be an angle at which the path touches the end point. It just seems that Chrome erroneously interprets the control point and the end point as defining a path segement of their own, which results in the error when these points coincide.

Comment: [The svg 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers/#OrientAttribute) is not crystal clear on the definition of directionality. It is not just bezier c.p, other edge cases can also yield similar behavior. This is the reason why I said based on the "ending" of the path. Normally, the user agent would determine the angle based on current end point and a "sufficiently close" previous point, much like taking a derivative. To show that I included an example in my answer. But someone also tried to attack me personally in morning comments, however he seems to have deleted it. Amazing consistency.

Answer (score -1):

- First, the ref attributes are sort of correct but can be better I think, make the refX 0 since you using the full viewBox.
- I think the marker's orientation is correct and updated. But based on the ending of the path, the interpolation of the orientation might look incorrect. So you can verify this behavior by cutting your pathstring from the last C... curve and will see that the orientation is correct.
- I further tested it to see if it is correct, at least for line segments, here is a fiddle and i didn't even use d3:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/L8x19rco/2/

```
var path = document.querySelector("path[stroke]");
var arr = Array.apply(null,Array(path.getTotalLength()/4 << 0)).map(function(d,i){
    var p = this.getPointAtLength(i*4);
  return [p.x,p.y];
},path);
var length = arr.length;
animate();

function animate(index){
    if(index >= length){
    return;
  }
    var index = index || 0;
  path.setAttribute("d","M"+arr.slice(1,Math.min(++index+1,length)).join("L"));
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){animate(index);});
}
```

Comment: I'm using a point (circle) to move it along a curved path using d3.js, I'll try to use this solution to move a marker instead of point. but I'm not sure if it will work. thank you anyway.